# Cant find the game to this melody. Something about Nintendo and Game Over Screen

Tags: game-identification

The background melody from this song:

https://soundcloud.com/lowcliqueboys/holy-rain-og-bobby-johnson

seems to be very familiar. Something from Nintendo i guess. I thought it was form the Tales of series but I couldnt find the melody there. Seems to be a Game Over melody aswell.

*EDIT*: Someone in the comment sections says it's a chrono trigger sample and now im looking throught the OST of that game to find the melody.

Comment: Also, just for future reference, you should not directly address people who downvote *(or upvote)* your questions, as this tends to attract negative attention to your posts.

Comment: im a bit pissed because i personally dont see the purpose of downvoting a post when i try to sort out all the problems i made creating this post. I even answered it myself and im active to comments. it has happened to me before when i commented on a religious topic where i didnt even offend a minority, but i still managed to get -3 on my score.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I'm guessing the reason for the initial downvote is because game identification questions are typically off-topic for this site (not always, but most of the time). So someone saw you were trying to identify some game, and downvoted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it!

Chrono Trigger ~~ At the Bottom of the Night

Comment: Is it sad or awesome that I was able to place the game instanly?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I believe it was stated that the cover art was done before Marle and Lucca were different people